# Vector addition in right angled triangle

Tags: vectors

For a right angled triangle in terms of vectors can I say the following?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is correct. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction)

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You are using [Chasles' Relation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Chasles'_Relation). 
And even if it wasn't a right angled triangle you could say it.